# Zend_Form setAttrib title not translating with Zend_Translate

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-translate

When setting the title attribute in Zend_Form, this is not being translated. (Label & errors are translated fine)

// form file

```
$email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
$email->setLabel('auth.form.login.username')
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->addFilter('StripTags')
      ->addFilter('StringTrim')
      ->addFilter('StringToLower')
      ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
      ->setAttrib('title', 'auth.form.login.username');
```

// resource file

```
...
<tu tuid='auth.form.login.username'>
   <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>Username</seg></tuv>
</tu>
...
```

Current result: **auth.form.login.username**

Expected result: **Username**

Comment: I can't remember that the attribute setter did translate. Looks like your expectation is wrong. Instead set the translated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behavior, nothing wrong with it.

The `setAttrib()` method **doesn't translate its value parameter**, so you need to use a Zend_Translate adapter as follows:

`$email->setAttrib('title', $this->getTranslator()->translate('auth.form.login.username'))`

This should fix your problem.

See [Standard I18n Targets](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.form.i18n.html#zend.form.i18n.standard) for more information.

> Now that you've attached a translation object to, what exactly can you
>   translate by default?
>
> - Validation error messages.
> - Labels.
> - Fieldset Legends.
> - Form and Element Descriptions.
> - Multi-option Values.
> - Submit and Button Labels.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly :). I didnt see this in the documentation?